# What happens if my luggage goes over the weight limit?

Tags: air-travel, luggage, regulations, united-airlines

Im traveling with United airways economy, I am allowed to have 2 bags (But i gotta pay for them) and each can be 50 LBS. I am scared that I might go over the max weight limit for my bags.

If this was to happened, what would happen? Would I have to pay more? If so how much more?

Comment: How much are you worried about going over by? 50.5lb instead of 50lb? 52lb? 55lb? 60lb? 70lb? 100lb?

Comment: A few years back I saw a Chinese couple (leaving the U.S.) that had a suitcase that was extremely overweight. It was so heavy it took both of them to lift it on the scale. I don't know how heavy it was but the airline wouldn't allow it as it was. They provided the couple with a clear extremely heavy duty bag that was about the size of 5 standard kitchen garbage bags. The couple transferred a lot of the contents into the bag then the airline taped the bag closed and tagged it. In the end the bag was filled with chocolate such as Snickers and M&M's. I'm sure they paid for another luggage.

Answer (score 6):

You will have to pay more. The rates vary based on the flight and your status with the carrier. For example, if you are military or business/first class, you can bring 70 LBS bags.

The standard overweight fee for normal bags (your first two) is $100 if the bag is between 50.1 LBS and 70 LBS, and $200 if the bag is between 70.1 LBS and 100 LBS. Bags over 100 LBS are not allowed. If you are bringing more than two bags and are not military or business/first class, you will face additional charges. It may be cheaper to bring a 3rd bag than to bring two bags with one or both of them being heavy.

Check the [United Baggage Fee Calculator](http://www.united.com/CMS/en-US/travel/Pages/CheckedBaggage.aspx) for specific information for you.

In addition, they will put a sticker on your bag saying it is heavy.

Answer (score 1):

http://www.united.com/CMS/en-US/travel/Pages/BaggageExcess.aspx depends on the flight. You need to check on http://www.united.com/CMS/en-US/travel/Pages/CheckedBaggage.aspx but in general, domestic overweight is $100, transoceanic is $200. You could use a courier for some of your stuff at this prices...